# Как можно посмотреть сообщения передаваемые через websocket в Firefox?

Tags: websocket, firefox

У меня есть Firefox и есть сайт, на котором используется вебсокеты: http://websocket.org/echo.html

И хотелось узнать какие сообщения передаются по websocket между браузером и сервером.

---

Пример формы для тестирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в официальной статье: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Inspecting_web_sockets

Если кратно:

1. Открыть панель разработчика (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Перейти на вкладку **Сеть**
3. Для удобства, можно включить фильтр **WS**, чтобы видеть запросы от websocket
4. Кликнуть на **WS** запрос
5. Выбрать вкладку **Сообщения**

Наглядно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]